Has advanced Quarto been solved?
Has the advanced rules of Quarto (where the 2x2 square condition is also included) been solved?
And in the advanced rules, where is the best position for the first piece?

The advanced rules of Quarto were solved at a similar time to the regular rules (1998), and much like the regular rules it has been shown that with perfect play the advanced rules will result in a draw (along with a number of other extended rulesets).
That said the following is the table of Quarto results for both the standard and advanced games:



Win condition
Distinct Draws




rows, cols
1329371360640


rows, cols, squares
35347120896



As you might be able to guess from the outcome space for both games perfect play is virtually impossible for a human to memorize, so while the game is solved it's not solved for human play.
In addition even though the game is solved there's no definitive "best" opening move in Quarto, as the game's strategy is deeply intertwined with anticipating your opponent's moves and reacting to the evolving board state.
